# What does Achim Klienke mean when he says measure theory is a linear theory?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Achim Klienke, in his book "Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course", begins his chapter on Independence as follows:

[image]

He refers to measure theory as a *linear theory*.

What does he mean by this and how does probability theory allow "nonlinear" behavior?

I suspect he means that the basic exposition he gave did not include product spaces, but that material is much later in his book (past this chapter). He appears to still be using measure theory, yet now its supposedly "nonlinear"?

Can someone provide some insight into what makes measure theory linear...I don't think it necessarily is.

Comment: Integration is a linear operation and that makes measure theory linear.I have no clue why probability theory should be nonlinear though.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker exactly! Probability is expressed via measure theory, so how can they have divergent properties as basic as this one (linear vs nonlinear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what he meant but a good guess that he was referring to the fact that integrals are linear functionals.  Measure theory is really connected to observing linear functionals and vice versa and maybe the most important theorem in measure theory(Apart from Lesbesgue stuff) is Riesz representation:
 Theorem. Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. For any positive linear functional

$\psi  $ on $C_c(X)$, there is a unique regular Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that:
$$  \psi(f) = \int_X f(x) \, d \mu(x) \quad $$
for all $f$ in $C_c(X)$.

Because the measures are linear functionals they are not good at describing non linear relations between to functions, I think that what the author meant

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that insofar as measure theory is a theory of general integration, then the theory is linear -- but how can Probability, which is axiomatized and expressed via measure theory, not also be linear?

Comment: Spelling:..... vice versa...... Lesbesgue..............+1

Comment: @Bey well think of two independent variables the probability of both happening is not the sum of the probability’s as if it was a linear theory.

Comment: @postmortes I corrected it....

Comment: @Elad thanks for the clarification — how does probability theory go beyond measure theory to allow nonlinear effects? Measure theory has product measures that allow modeling independence — I suspect that the author was restricting his statements to the specific material presented in the chapter on basic measure theory (which didn’t look at space decompositions).

Comment: I think for him product measures is part of probability theory but thats just a guess

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Lebesgue. Not Lesbesgue.

Comment: @Insertnamehere . Of course. :)